# how to create a linked list with this struct as data?

Tags: arrays, c, list, struct

I am trying to print out a table, namely the first ten elements in the periodic table as a linked list with a struct as data. The struct holds the elements' data like so:

```
typedef struct element{
    char *name;
    char *symbol;
    float weight; 
}element;
```

and then creating the list itself likeso:

```
typedef struct list{
    struct element elements[]; //an array holding element types?
    struct list *next; 
}list;
```

so because I need to print out the first 10 elements, I tried using arrays to declare the names, symbols and weights, but I couldn't make the connection of which way to use that in the linked list as data:

```
char *names[10] = {"Hydrogen", "Helium", "Lithium", "Beryllium", "Boron", "Carbon", "Nitrogen", "Oxygen", "Fluorine", "Neon"};
char *symbols[10] = {"H","He","Li","Be","B","C","N","O","F","Ne"};
float weights[10] = {1.008,4.003,6.941,9.012,10.811,12.011,14.007,15.999,18.998,20.180};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the pointer the the next element. You do not need a new structure for it. Here is some example code (only adding to the list and printing implemented)

There is some code populating the list form the arrays.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct element{
    char *name;
    char *symbol;
    float weight;
    struct element *next;
}element;

element *addToList(element *head, const char *name, const char *symbol, float weight)
{
    element *current, tmp;
    if(!head)
    {
        head = realloc(head, sizeof(*head));
        current = head;
    }
    else
    {
        element *wrk;
        current = head;
        while(current -> next) current = current ->next;
        wrk = malloc(sizeof(*head));
        if(wrk)
        {
            current -> next = wrk;
            current = wrk;
        }
    }
    if(current)
    {
        current -> name = malloc(strlen(name) + 1);
        current -> symbol = malloc(strlen(symbol) + 1);
        //add memory checks here
        strcpy(current -> name, name);
        strcpy(current -> symbol, symbol);
        current -> weight = weight;
        current -> next = NULL;
    }
    return head;
}

size_t printLinst(const element *head)
{
    size_t nelems = 0;
    while(head)
    {
        printf("%zu element = {\"%s\", \"%s\", %f}\n", ++nelems, head -> name, head -> symbol, head -> weight);
        head = head -> next;
    }
    return nelems;
}

/* another list functions */

char *names[10] = {"Hydrogen", "Helium", "Lithium", "Beryllium", "Boron", "Carbon", "Nitrogen", "Oxygen", "Fluorine", "Neon"};
char *symbols[10] = {"H","He","Li","Be","B","C","N","O","F","Ne"};
float weights[10] = {1.008,4.003,6.941,9.012,10.811,12.011,14.007,15.999,18.998,20.180};

#define ARRSIZE(arr) (sizeof((arr))/sizeof((arr)[0])) 

int main(void)
{
    element *head = NULL;

    for(size_t index = 0; index < ARRSIZE(weights); index++)
    {
        head = addToList(head, names[index], symbols[index], weights[index]);
    }

    printf("List is %zu elements long\n", printLinst(head));
    /* another code */
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/ddEzTx

Comment: thank you so much! Your code made me understand the code, and lists in general as well

Answer (score 2):

It is unusual for a linked list to have an array of elements, though there are cases where it can be useful. In your case I think a linked list where each list element has one element is more appropriate:

```
typedef struct list{
    struct element element;
    struct list *next; 
}list;
```

As a matter of style, we end up with the name `element` used in the structure name, as the typedef'd name and as a structure member. I suggest to rename them to `struct ELEMENT` and `tElement`. The same with the list structure. This will make it like:

```
typedef struct ELEMENT {
    char *name;
    char *symbol;
    float weight; 
} tElement;

typedef struct LIST {
    tElement element;
    struct LIST *next; 
} tList;
```

I leave it to you to develop the functions to create and add to the list and to print it.

Answer (score 1):

You have two main options for linked list structure:

1. The items contain the links, and so constitute linked list nodes in their own right:

   ```
   struct element {
       char *name;
       char *symbol;
       float weight; 
       struct element *next;   // <--- here
   };
   ```
2. List nodes and data are separate(-ish).  For example:

   ```
   struct element {
       char *name;
       char *symbol;
       float weight; 
   };

   struct node {
       struct element *element;  // points to the item
       struct node *next;
   };
   ```

   or maybe

   ```
   struct node {
       struct element element;   // contains the item
       struct node *next;
   };
   ```

There can be a separate structure for the list itself, but there doesn't have to be.  The minimal representation of the list is simply a pointer to the head node:

```
struct node *head;
```

It is not usual for there to be a structure containing the nodes directly, as you propose, because requiring the nodes to be drawn from such a pool would limit the maximum size of the list.  There are other reasons why it can be useful to have a structure type representing the overall list, but that's probably more complexity than you need to worry about for your present task.

Whether you want to declare `typedef` aliases for your structure types is an entirely separate question, by the way.  I rarely do so, myself.  It is largely a style question, but I bring it up because some people have the mistaken impression that `typedef` is an essential element of the definition of a structure type.